# Do loans have interest?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I was sure I paid 2k out of the 10k loan I took yesterday. But this morning, it was back a 10k to pay.

Do the loans have interest, or reset every day? Or did I just imagine that I had paid 2k off it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no interest on the loans from OK Motors.

Comment: Ok I must have not confirmed my payment yesterday I guess